# Control Website Folder Access using Web.config and session variable?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, security, session, web-config

the following web.config file is placed in a specific sub-folder on a website. It will allow the user **John.Doe** to access the pages inside the folder but will deny anonymous users

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <authorization>
        <allow users="John.Doe" />
        <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

Is it possible to replace **users** in the following web.config file with certain session variable

for example getting the day(sunday, monday, etc) from date and storing it in session("DayVar")
then the code should be something like this for the subfolder **monday**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <authorization>
        <allow session("DayVar")="monday" />
        <deny session("DayVar")<>"monday"/>
    </authorization>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

is this doable ?

Answer (score 1):

This is not something that is built into the framework.

You could handle this via a custom base page or similar to implement that type of restriction.